# How do I make this image larger?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

I wanted my application to have a responsive design so I used the "wrap content" attribute to align my image. However, my image looks extremely small. How could I enlarge it while maintaining a responsive design?

Code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_welcome_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_trivial_trivia"/>
```

Comment: **FOR BEST PERFORMANCE:** Try increasing the size of your image outside of android studio. In actual fact, there are numerous ways you can make your image appear bigger in your imageview but most of these methods would distort and reduce the quality of your image (because it's actually being stretched beyond its dimensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without the rest of your layout, but you're limiting yourself to the width of the image here.

What if you set the width to `match_parent`? That way the height becomes the determining factor until the width is filled.

You could also set a background on your `ImageView` while testing to see the bounds of the `ImageView` itself (as opposed to the bounds of the image within it).

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated.

Comment: Right ... I never remember which without the IDE's help ;)